# Get value from string based on RegEx

Tags: linux, bash, centos7

I have a bash script that I am trying to learn from. I have a sql file that has in it:

```
create user myuser with password 'mypassword';
```

I want to use sed and store the value of the password in one bash variable and the pasword in another bash variable. The script that I am learning from has:

```
USERNAME := $(shell sed -n \
"s/^create user \(\S\+\) with password '\(\S\+\)';$$/\1/p" \
createdb.sql)
PASSWORD := $(shell sed -n \
"s/^create user \(\S\+\) with password '\(\S\+\)';$$/\2/p" \
createdb.sql)
```

No matter what I tried the regex would not match up. Part of my issue is I don't understand the basics of sed. How do I go about getting the value of parts of the string?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `sed` for this; use `bash`'s built-in regular expression support.

```
str="create user myuser with password 'mypassword';"
regex='create user (.*) with password (.*);'
if [[ $str =~ $regex ]]; then
    username=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    password=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
fi
```

As for how you *get* the appropriate line in the first place, use `grep`:

```
str=$(grep "create user" createddb.sql)
```

Comment: $str in this case would be the file?

Comment: hm... using external `grep` and after bash builtin regex, instead of one external sed + read?

Comment: You could, but I find this a little simpler. It essentially uses a multi-character delimiter `with password` to separate the two values, rather than trying to come up with a safe single-character delimiter to use in `IFS` to let `read` resplit the output of `sed`.

Comment: As long as you could find a character that doesn't appear in the *user* (which in this case is probably trivial), something like `IFS=% read user passwd < <(sed 's/create user (.*) with password (.*)/\1%\2/')` would be fine. On the other extreme, you could even forgo the call to `grep` by using a `while` loop to read the file line by line, but I suspect `grep` would be faster unless you have a very small file or the line in question is found early. `grep` + `=~` just happens to be (IMO) the simplest balance between two extremes.